# How to find words ending with ing

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am looking to find words ending with ing and print them, my current code prints out ing instead of the word.

```
#match all words ending in ing
import re
expression = input("please enter an expression: ")
print(re.findall(r'\b\w+(ing\b)', expression))
```

so if we enter as an expression : `sharing all the information you are hearing`

I would like `['sharing', 'hearing']` to be printed out
instead I am having `['ing', 'ing']` printed out

Is there a quick way to fix that ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your capture grouping is wrong try the following :

```
>>> s="sharing all the information you are hearing"
>>> re.findall(r'\b(\w+ing)\b',s)
['sharing', 'hearing']
```

Also you can use `str.endswith` method within a list comprehension :

```
>>> [w for w in s.split() if w.endswith('ing')]
['sharing', 'hearing']
```

Answer (score 4):

Parentheses "capture" text from your string.  You have `'(ing\b)'`, so only the `ing` is being captured.  Move the open parenthesis so it encompasses the entire string that you want: `r'\b(\w+ing)\b'`.  See if that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Try this. It'll work!

```
import re
expression = input("please enter an expression: ")
pattern = "\w+ing"
result = re.findall(pattern, expression)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sentence = 'sharing all the information you are hearing'
# spit so we have list of words from sentence
words =  sentence.split(' ')


ending_with('ing',words)

def ending_with(ending, words):
    # loop through words
    for word in words:
        # if word has ends with ending
        if word.endswith(ending):
            # print
            print word
```