# Search partial word and replace it with regex

Tags: python, regex

I have several words in text, which have last three letter same. For example icat, iacat, wddcat and scat. The length of words are not same. They vary from 4 letters to 7 letters. I want to replace all the words with CAT.

Input:

```
text = 'hi i want to replace acat'
```

Output:

```
text = 'hi i want to replace CAT'
```

Can I use regular expression for my case?

Comment: Please update your question with what you have tried so far along with the specific issues/errors you are getting

Comment: thank you for your quick Reply. I tried many things and ended up with nothing. I do not have concrete Code right now after many Trial. @ I.T Delinquent

Comment: Your answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29680287/how-to-find-words-ending-with-ing). Just use it with `re.sub`

Comment: @user11603027: you can still show what you have tried. It's OK that it doesn't work - people just want to see that you have tried something.

Comment: Ohh, yes. I didn't know about it. Actually I am new to python and stack Overflow.
Thank you for pointing out my attenton. I have solution right now. I will do it next time. @I.T Delinquent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try searching for the regex pattern `\w*cat\w*` in case insensitive mode, and then replace all matches with `CAT`:

```
text = 'hi i want to replace acat'
output = re.sub(r'\w*cat\w*', 'CAT', text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
hi i want to replace CAT
```

Comment: Give me a shout if you need a (virtual) hug! I'm that guy in the shopping centre, with the Free Hugs sign.